# How to read or loop each sheets on csv/xls using FileStream and StreamReader on C#

Tags: c#, excel, filestream, streamreader, csv-import

This example code below is an example on how do I read headers and each line of csv/xls using FileStream and StreamReader in C#. It's all working, but only with one sheet.

```
                using (var fs = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default))
                    {
                        line1 = sr.ReadLine();
                        string[] headers = line1.Split(","); //THIS LINE WILL READ HEADERS
                        
                        if (headers.Length > 0)
                        {
                            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                //HERE WILL READ EACH LINE 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Now I have multiple sheets. The question is how do I read or jump to another sheets.

With the code above what do I need to add?

Example pic for
[multiple sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHfrl.png)

Comment: IIRC, a CVS file have no concept of sheets. For XLS files, I'm pretty sure there are packages that can handle that for you without forcing you to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Is there any sample packages you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the "DocumentFormat.OpenXml" package. Accessing sheets like you want to takes a little bit of extra code, but Microsoft provide some great help with this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-get-worksheet-information-from-a-package